# onclick+ settimeout event is not working in Chromebase system for chrome extension app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, settimeout, ontouchlistener, chromebook

I have created the chrome extension. My code is working fine in Windows/Mac/Chromebook(V8) but it is not working in Chromebase while user in trying to tap/trap the logo after that 3 minutes,it is not redirecting on the home page. I have setup the timeout for 3 minutes and its working on all system instead of Chrombase touch event.

Strange thing is that it is working for the first time only.

**My code is the below from reset timeout and DOM element:**

```
    var t;  
    onload = function() {
      var webview = document.querySelector('webview');
      window.onload = resetTimer;
      // DOM Events
      document.onclick = resetTimer;
      document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
      document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
     };



    function resetTimer() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(goHome, 180000);
    // 1000 milisec = 1 sec
    }

    function goHome() {
     navigateTo('http://MyURL.com/homepage/');
    }  


  function navigateTo(url) {
    document.querySelector('webview').src = url;
    }
```

Also, I have also search over google for the touch event like touchstart,touchmove but it seems that it is also not working..

what can be issue? please help

Comment: is there any way to solve this issue @wOxxOm? please help

Comment: its chrome private enterprise extension @wOxxOm

Comment: I can only suggest debugging using devtools. If you don't own the device, suggest your client to set up a TeamViewer session.

Comment: if we add the  touch event like touchstart,touchmove with reset timer then it can work?... what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Please use [Chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms) instead of settimeout.

Your code should replace with below code.

```
var t;  
onload = function() {
  var webview = document.querySelector('webview');
  window.onload = resetTimer;
  // DOM Events
  document.onclick = resetTimer;
  document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
  document.onkeypress = resetTimer;

  document.ontouchstart = resetTimer;
  document.ontouchmove = resetTimer;
  document.ontouchend = resetTimer;   
 };

 function resetTimer() {

    chrome.alarms.clear("logoutTimer", function() {     });
    chrome.alarms.create("logoutTimer", {periodInMinutes:1});
   }


 chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm){

   navigateTo('http://dev.innovicloud.com/CHROMEAPP/');
 });



function navigateTo(url) {
  document.querySelector('webview').src = url;
 }
```